# How to define a type that accepts template strings but not literal strings

Tags: typescript

I would like to define a type that accepts only template strings, but NOT literal strings.

```js
type TemplateOnly = /* ??? */

const foo: TemplateOnly = `hello` // allowed
const bar: TemplateOnly = 'world' // error
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think this is possible. There is nothing more specific for this than type `string`. But I'd love to see somebody prove me wrong.

Comment: this is not possible, `\`hello\`` has exactly the same type as `'hello'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template strings are **not a type**, but a language construct.

As such you cannot use them as a type.
More over, you could use template strings, with tagged template to return whatever type you want.

Think about it like this: you could have a string created by concatenating more strings. Something like this

`const a = "something" + " " + 5`

You are asking to be able to make a choice, between a concatenating string and an "inline" was.